# How to Convert a string to number in freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

I want to convert a string to number in freemarker. I want to put some conditional check based on the value of the number. ?number doesn't seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you're doing, how, and version--`number` works fine for me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sorry, `?number` does work fine. I was not able to compare the converted number with another number.

This didn't work for me:

```
<#assign num = numString?number>

<#if num > 100>
</#if>
```

When I enclosed (num > 100) inside the brackets it worked:

```
<#if (num > 100)>
</#if>
```

Since the comparison was not working, I was assuming that conversion was not happening.
My bad.

Comment: `<#if num >` should give an error saying that the value must be a number but it was a number.

Comment: is it possible to convert number like this : 1,000 to 1000 in freemarker ?

Comment: Freemarker doesn't like plain > and < since it cannot always tell if they are tags or not.  I typically use &lt; and &gt;.  See [Freemarker Manual](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison)

Comment: @Mady and others: you might need both: value?c?number

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you use the closed bracket, so freemarker is evaluating

```
<#if num >
```

you should instead use

```
<#if num gt 100>
```

This is discussed at the end of this documentation on if statements
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html

The reason this is working for some and not others is because of the parentheses, which is also explained at the bottom of the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use it like this:`string?eval`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
<#if num?string > 100?string>
</#if>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`string?number` should work, but has some restrictions on the format (see [documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_number)), which sometimes makes it hard to work with.

You can use `string?eval` ([documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_eval)) instead to make Freemarker evaluate the content of your variable and convert it to a number if that is determined to be the content.

So:

```
<#if string?eval &gt 100>
"do one thing"
<#else> 
"something else"
</#if>
```

Note that &gt (greater than) is used instead of > to prevent confusion with other code tags [(source)](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison).